# Can not connect to Truffle or testrpc with Ganache GUI

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, appx, ganache

I have Ganache GUI from appx from official website on my Windows 10. When I run Truffle or testrpc network in my console (WSL) and try to connect there from Ganache GUI in settings, I get error message next to the textbox with a port:

> The port is used by another application; please change it

[image]

the port is from Truffle or testrpc. How can I connect there? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ganache UI runs an instance of Ganache CLI (i.e. simulated Ethereum instance previously called TestRPC). If you already have a console window open with an application on port 9545 then Ganache UI cannot start a new instance on that same port.

Comment: so how can I connect the GanacheUI to the Truffle?

Comment: It's the other way around. You'd want to connect Truffle to GancheUI. In your `truffle.js` configuration file be sure to the `host` to `127.0.0.1`, the `port` to `9545` and the `network_id` to `5777` or `*`. This will allow you to then be able to use Truffle to deploy and interact with contracts on your simulated network created via GancheUI.

Answer (score 1):

I add the following to my .zshrc or .bashrc file

```
# Get WSL Host IP
export WSL_HOST_IP="$(awk '/nameserver/ { print $2 }' /etc/resolv.conf)"
```

This allows me to surface my host ip, so commands in WSL2 can reach the localhost.

Now create a workspace in Ganache GUI and under the server HOSTNAME settings choose "0.0.0.0 - All Interfaces".

In your truffle project edit the truffle-config.js file and set your network development block to this:

```
development: {
  host: process.env.WSL_HOST_IP,
  port: 7545,
  network_id: "*" // Match any network id
}
```

Now when you run truffle migrate, it should connect to the Ganache GUI.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get a connection timeout (my internet is not slow) error. I've seen your other post on GH and ethereum stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that worked for me:

- Start ganache-ui
- Configure truffle's network in `truffle-config.js`:

```
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    ...
```

- Run `truffle console` (NOT `truffle develop`)